# Derivation of partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

So this follows Schroeder's Intro to Thermal Physics equations 6.1-6.7, but the question isn't book specific. Please let me be clear: I know for a fact I'm wrong. However, it feels like performing seemingly allowed manipulations, I arrive at an incorrect conclusion... what gives?

We say that:

$$ \text{Boltzmann factor} = e^{-E \beta} $$

Where $ \beta = 1/k_b T$.

But we know by the 1st law that $ dS_R = dU / T$ (All the other terms are 0 or negligible). So, for isothermic situations, $ U = TS$. Additionally, $S(E) = k_b \ln \Omega(E) $ (all of these are used by Schroeder so I think they're right), and then:

$$ E = -U = -T k_b \ln(\Omega(E))$$

And if we solve for $ \Omega$, we get:

$$\Omega(E) = e^{-E / (k_b T)} = e^{-E \beta}  = \text{Boltzmann factor} $$

But this is nowhere mentioned in the book, and seems important and/or horribly wrong! Moreover, this means that $$ Z = \text{ Total # of accessible microstates at all energies} $$ Which is also nowhere mentioned, and feels very important! Where did I go wrong? This feels very important and yet doesn't seem to be mentioned... anywhere.

This all falls apart even harder with the magnetic dipole example, because we start to get stuff like:

$$ P(E) = \frac{ e^{-E \beta} \Omega(E) }{Z} = \frac{\Omega^2(E)}{\text{Total # of Microstates}} $$

I suspect that in this case the error is due to the fact $\Omega(E) \neq \text{Degeneracy}(E)$, but I'm not sure about that, because it seems to indicate that the $\Omega$ represents something that isn't the number of microstates, but some other number entirely.

Comment: The first part in your question I began to disagree was when you said $U=TS$. How do you get that? You can't just integrate the thermodynamic relationship and assume $T$ is constant, because doing that integral corresponds to *adding energy from $U=0$*, or equivalently raising the temperature from zero.

Comment: Hm - that makes sense. The only question I have then is what enables Schroeder to say, when comparing two different states (in the same context), to say that $ S(s_2) - S(s_1) = 1/T [U(s_2) - U(s_1)] $?

Comment: Looking at my copy of Schroder, he's talking about a very specific situation: A system in contact with a large reservoir. The $U$ and $S$ he's using correspond to the $U$ and $S$ of the RESERVOIR, which is assumed to be so large that $T$ doesn't change. But he then derives an identity for the system that the reservoir is in contact with. At the end of the day, Boltzmann statistics are only rigorously derived for a small system in equilibrium with a large thermal reservoir.

Comment: That follows, thank you! My confusion (mostly) came from the blind application of the partition function - this all nicely resolves my questions; thanks again.